# Xcode 5 doesn't let me adding Icons and Launch Images

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am using Xocde 5 , in my Phone Project I am working on I am having some problem on adding Icons and Launch Images to my project. I don't use storyboard and asset catalog , so I always delete them after creating a new project.

[image]

Usually, when "Don't use asset catalog" is selected in the Launch Images and Icons section in general tab of project settings , I see there's option for adding images for different screen sizes. But currently, I don't get that options. "Don't use asset catalog" is selected here , but there's no other things on that menu and right arrow icon beside that does nothing when I click that. So, It seems there's no way I can add launch images and app icons to my project.

Can anyone give me some hint , how can I resolve that. I have to add Launch Images and App Icons. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve it. I have copied Images.xcassets file from another project and added to my project. Then I got the options to add images in the place I mentioned in the attached image in the question. So, I have deleted the images that came from other projects in the asset catalog and add the necessary files there from my project. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be by adding a 'New App Icon' and/or 'New Launchimage' in the Assets Catalog and then select the created image sets in project settings.